# How can I thwart Chrome's caching of jQuery.load()ed files?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, caching, ahah

I've run into this problem once before, and am hitting it again. I have a webpage that may make AHAH loads via `jQuery.load()`. The text that was loaded appears to stay in the cache, and the usual shift-reload is not enough: it loads the parent document but keeps its cached copy of the loaded data.

What is the best way to make sure that a page and everything loaded works? Close the page and obliterate appropriate browsing data? I've circumvented the problem this time by loading from another browser, but I wanted to know if there is any developer-friendly mode that causes updates in AHAH `jQuery.load()`ed data to show up.

Comment: I'm 99% certain you cna't access cache or header controls within the `.load()` wrapper for `.ajax()`. You could try `$.ajaxSetup({ cache : false });`, or you could just simply change to a `$.ajax()` command and leverage the `beforeSend` exposing the `jqXHR` object, and allowing you to modify any headers, along with `cache: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F12, click on the cogwheel in the lower right corner and make sure "Disable cache" is checked. Chrome seems to only honor this setting as long as the developer tools are open.